# How to make DataFrame plot bars be shown in different colors?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I am a newbie data analyst and I am trying to create a dataframe bar chart with df.plot() so that the bars have different colors. I found out that there are no arguments that can be passed to color the bars in different colors unless the dataframe is transposed. I tried to transpose it with the below code:

```
gender_overview = pd.read_sql("SELECT Gender, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfPeople "
                          "FROM [AdventureWorks2019].[Sales].[vPersonDemographics] "
                          "GROUP BY Gender "
                          "ORDER BY NumberOfPeople DESC;", conn)

display(gender_overview)
df = gender_overview.set_index('Gender')
ax = df.T.plot(kind='bar', label='index', colormap='Paired')
labels = ['Male', 'Female', 'Not Specified']
ax.set_xticks(range(len(df)))
ax.set_xticklabels(labels=labels, rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

however, the bars and x_ticks ended up to be mismatched (please see the screenshot
[here.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVc9R.png)

How can I make sure that bars match with the respective x_ticks?

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you must transpose the DF. Try without, I just did and it didn't complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that I cannot use Pandas for plotting when I want some fine control. I tend to lean on matplotlib.

```
import panda as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['test'] = np.arange(6)
df['gender'] = ['M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F']
df.set_index('gender', inplace=True)

plt.bar(df.index, df['test'], color=['blue', 'red'])
plt.show()
```

It's tempting to try the group-by, but I don't think it helps.

```
g = df.groupby("gender").count()
plt.bar(g.index, g['test'], color=['blue', 'red'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot for your advice! It's really much easier with Matplotlib

Comment: That's great. Matplotlib is a bit confusing coming from MATLAB but eventually it makes sense.